# AppSync Resolver does not return null for null-able array field, but [null]

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I am using the following Graphql schema:

```
Connection {
  items: [String]
}
```

connected to the DynamoDB response resolver:

```
{
}
```

which is obviously empty, but still, the GraphiQL console of AWS returns an **array with one null element**:

```
{
  data: {
    items: [null]
  }
}
```

Is this an intended behavior? I would expect the returned result to be

```
{
  data: {
    items: null
  }
}
```

(without the array, just null). How do I get **Appsync to only return null?**

Comment: What is your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This setup returns null for items.

Schema:

```
type Connection {
  items: [String]
}

query {
  listNull: Connection
}
```

Request template:

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "Scan",
}
```

Response Template:

```
{
}
```

Query:

```
query ListNull {
  listNull {
    items
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "listNull": {
      "items": null
    }
  }
}
```